# How to calculate $R^2$ for LASSO (glmnet)

Tags: r, multiple-regression, lasso, r-squared, glmnet

I am confused how to calculate r-squared for the glmnet fits (LASSO, elastic-net etc). One of the ways I have seen is through the cvm corresponding to one of lambdas:

```
cvfit2 <- glmnet::cv.glmnet(datam, fundm,alpha=1,nfolds=10)
cf<-coef(cvfit2, s = "lambda.1se")
i<-which(cvfit2$lambda == cvfit2$lambda.1se)
e<-cvfit2$cvm[i]
r2<-1-e/var(fundm)
r2
#[1]  0.4571688
```

The classic way via calculating the variance of the residuals:

```
datam2<-as.matrix(datam)
cc2<-as.matrix(cf[-1,]) #removing the intercept row
predict<-datam2 %*% cc2
err<-predict - fundm
View(err)
r2b<-1-var(err)/var(fundm)
r2b
#[1] 0.6100457
```

Quite a huge difference and I am not sure if the 1st way of calculating $R^2$ is correct.

**My questions**

1. What is the correct way of calculating r-squared?
2. A glmnet object has components dev.ratio and nulldev. From the glmnet docs:

   *"The fraction of (null) deviance explained (for "elnet", this is the R-square)."*

Should we rather use dev.ratio for the purpose of $R^2$ calculations? If yes, how to extract it for the given lambda index? The dev.ratio array has 100 values, but the `cvfit2$lambda` has only 88 values.

I am really confused and would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using

```
r2 <- fit$glmnet.fit$dev.ratio[which(fitnet$glmnet.fit$lambda == fitnet$lambda.min)]
```

or if you have chosen the lambda.1se

```
r2 <- fit$glmnet.fit$dev.ratio[which(fitnet$glmnet.fit$lambda == fitnet$lambda.1se)]
```

If you do a cross check with the traditional regression lm() and summary()$r.squared it will match the results if weights are close to the elastic net.

Comment: Believe your code should either reference `fit` or `fitnet` - not both?

Comment: I found this code confusing at first, but after playing with it a little, it seems to me that if `regr` is the regression model, then `glmnet.fit` is a column of `regr`. Therefore, `fitnet` is his regression model and `glmnet.fit` are different things!

Answer (score 1):

I think I know why the two calculations produce different answers.  The `cvm` variable from the `cvm.glmnet` object is a cross-validated error.  It's calculated from the residuals in the validation folds.  The `predict()` function on the other hand, is not cross-validated.  It's calculated from the residuals of predictions on the whole data set.